# Adobe Animate EXE and Analytics

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, adobe-animate

I am trying to find a solution for integrating Google Analytics into an Adobe Animate exe file. I know there is information about plugging [Google Analytics into Flash](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/flashTrackingIntro), which I had hoped would work in Adobe Animate CC, but it does not.

Has anyone tried this or know of a solution to make Google Analytics function correctly in an Adobe Animate EXE file?

Comment: I don't actually remember details for it was few years ago, but I used GA with AS3 and it was pretty easy. I just looked through you link, there are 2 SWC libraries you probably need to link to your project for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/flashTrackingSetupFlash

This should work as it spells out the solution for you right here.

```
import com.google.analytics.AnalyticsTracker;
import com.google.analytics.GATracker;
var tracker:AnalyticsTracker = new GATracker( this, "UA-111-222", "AS3", true );
playGame.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClick );
function onButtonClick ( event:Event ):void
{
   tracker.trackPageview("/myGame1");
}
```

Simply include the SWC, import the necessary elements (either in frame code or in a separate class file) and start tracking.